# what is the difference between innerHeight and offsetHeight in javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am implementing a scrollbar feature in javascript. I am unable to understand the difference between  innerHeight and offsetHeight in javascript.
I am following a tutorial whose code is mentioned below.

```
  const handleScroll = () => {
        if(window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight || loading)
        {
            return false;
        }

        setLoading(true)
    }
```

Any clear explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

### [`Window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight)

> Height (in pixels) of the browser window viewport including, if rendered, the horizontal scrollbar.

`innerHeight` says something about the window of the browser. It is the height of the viewport that you are viewing in, from the top to the bottom of the page. `outerHeight` will include the browser address bar, controls, tabs and others elements that are in your view. `innerHeight` and `outerHeight` are exclusive to the `window` object.

### [`HTMLElement.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)

> Typically, offsetHeight is a measurement in pixels of the element's CSS height, including any borders, padding, and horizontal scrollbars (if rendered). It does not include the height of pseudo-elements such as ::before or ::after. For the document body object, the measurement includes total linear content height instead of the element's CSS height. Floated elements extending below other linear content are ignored.

The offsetHeight says something about the height of an element defined by CSS. So if you have an element with `height: 100px;` then the `offsetHeight` will be `100`.